# How to parse offset with colon using DateTimeFormatter?

Tags: java, datetime, parsing, java-8, dateformatter

I have the following string: `String timeStamp = "2020-01-31 12:13:14 +03:00"`.
And I tried to parse it using Java 8 DateTimeFormatter.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( format );
tmpTimestamp = ZonedDateTime.parse( timeStamp, formatter );
```

where `format` is one of:

```
"yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss' 'Z",
"yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss' 'X",
"yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss' 'x",
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z",
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss X",
"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss x",
```

None is working. Always I got `DateTimeParseException` either pointing to '+' or to ':' character in offset substring "+03:00"

According to JavaDocs: [Class DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) "+03:00" shall be supported by any of: `Z`, `X` and `x`.

So the question is how to construct formatter string to parse it?

Comment: @MS90 - not `LocalDateTime`, but rather `OffsetDateTime` (since it has an offset).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the times `X` (`yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss XXX`):

```
String timeStamp = "2020-01-31 12:13:14 +03:00";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss XXX");
ZonedDateTime tmpTimestamp = ZonedDateTime.parse(timeStamp, formatter);
```

From the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html):

> **Offset X and x:** This formats the offset based on the number of pattern letters.
>
> One letter outputs just the hour, such as '+01', unless the minute is non-zero in which case the minute is also output, such as '+0130'.
>
> Two letters outputs the hour and minute, without a colon, such as '+0130'.
>
> **Three letters outputs the hour and minute, with a colon, such as '+01:30'.**
>
> Four letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, without a colon, such as '+013015'.
>
> Five letters outputs the hour and minute and optional second, with a colon, such as '+01:30:15'.
>
> Six or more letters throws IllegalArgumentException.
>
> Pattern letter 'X' (upper case) will output 'Z' when the offset to be output would be zero, whereas pattern letter 'x' (lower case) will output '+00', '+0000', or '+00:00'.

Alternative you can use five letters (`XXXXX`) and you also can use `ZZZ` or `ZZZZZ` instead of `XXX` or `XXXXX`.

Answer (score 4):

From the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)

> **Offset Z**: This formats the offset based on the number of pattern
>   letters. One, two or three letters outputs the hour and minute,
>   without a colon, such as '+0130'. The output will be '+0000' when the
>   offset is zero. Four letters outputs the full form of localized
>   offset, equivalent to four letters of Offset-O. The output will be the
>   corresponding localized offset text if the offset is zero. **Five
>   letters outputs the hour, minute, with optional second if non-zero,
>   with colon.** It outputs 'Z' if the offset is zero. Six or more letters
>   throws IllegalArgumentException.

You need 5 Z's

```
String format = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZZ";
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/TGjtlg)

Answer (score 4):

You don’t need to fiddle with a format pattern string.

```
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder()
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .append(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_TIME)
            .appendLiteral(' ')
            .appendOffsetId()
            .toFormatter();
    String timeStampString = "2020-01-31 12:13:14 +03:00";
    OffsetDateTime dateTime = OffsetDateTime.parse(timeStampString, formatter);
    System.out.println(dateTime);
```

It’s wordier, but harder to get wrong. I’m just assembling the formatter from built-in parts. Output is:

> 2020-01-31T12:13:14+03:00

I am also parsing into an `OffsetDateTime` instead of a `ZonedDateTime`. Since the string contains an offset (+03:00) and no time zone (such as America/Boa_Vista), even though it would probably work with a `ZonedDateTime`, `OffsetDateTime` is the correct class to use.